# Chapter Title and its name on middle of page

Tags: titlesec, titling

I use following code for sectioning of my title page of thesis. First two chapters title and chapter number is in mid of seperate page and text is started from next page,but next chapters start from top with text. Can any one guide me in this regard.

```
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\Large\filcenter\sffamily}
{\titlerule[1pt]%
\vspace{1pt}%
\titlerule
\vspace{1pc}%
\LARGE\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter}
{1pc}
{\titlerule
\vspace{1pc}%
\Huge}
[\newpage]
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an attempt

```
\documentclass{report}

%\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}

%\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\Large\filcenter\sffamily}
{\titlerule[1pt]%
\vspace{1pt}%
\titlerule
\vspace{1pc}%
\LARGE\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter}
{1pc}
{\titlerule
\vspace{1pc}%
\Huge}

\begin{document}


\begingroup
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\vfill\normalfont\Large\filcenter\sffamily}
{\titlerule[1pt]%
\vspace{1pt}%
\titlerule
\vspace{1pc}%
\LARGE\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter}
{1pc}
{\titlerule
\vspace{1pc}%
\Huge}
[\vfill\clearpage] 

\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-2.25ex}{0pt}
\chapter{First vertically centered chapter}
\lipsum
\chapter{Second vertically centred chapter}
\endgroup
\lipsum
\chapter{normal chapter}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]